Interior angle formula for generic quadrilateral
Suppose we have quadrilateral with vertices {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {a, b}, {c, d}}. Do there exist formulas for each interior angle that produce correct result for all possible values of a, b, c, d?
I derived these formulas but the third one fails, for example, for a = 3/4, b = 1/2, c = 1, d = 3/2. It produces 2.43297 while the correct answer is 2 Pi - 2.43297 = 3.85022. Basically the fomulas fail at concave angle.
How to fix this?
(By the way I am aware that arccos output range is (0, Pi) but that is the point of the question - how to amend the formula that its output range is (0, 2 Pi).)
$$\begin{array}{l}
 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}\right) \\
 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-a}{\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}}\right) \\
 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{(1-a) (c-a)-b (d-b)}{\sqrt{(1-a)^2+b^2}
   \sqrt{(c-a)^2+(d-b)^2}}\right) \\
 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{-(c (a-c))-d (b-d)}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}
   \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}\right) \\
\end{array}$$


To avoid range restrictions of inverse trig functions, it often makes sense to use the "$\operatorname{atan2}$" function.

@Blue Great suggestion. I will try to use it in my formulas instead of arcos.
